# How I create a Sql mock unit test Grails

Tags: sql, unit-testing, testing, grails

I'm Trying to unit test Grails and what I have tried is given below:

```
def getMarca(CrDocumento crDocumento) {
    if (!crDocumento) {
        return null
    }
    String sql = ""

    sql = "select marca.id as marca_id from cr_documento, matricula, cr_renegoc_boleto, oferta_polo_turma, oferta_polo, oferta, marca where cr_documento.id = cr_renegoc_boleto.cr_documento_id and cr_documento.matricula_id = matricula.id and matricula.oferta_polo_turma_id = oferta_polo_turma.id and oferta_polo_turma.oferta_polo_id = oferta_polo.id and oferta_polo.oferta_id = oferta.id and oferta.marca_id = marca.id and cr_documento.id = $crDocumento.id"

    def sqlGroovy = new Sql(dataSource)
    def marcaId = sqlGroovy.firstRow(sql)?.marca_id
    return Marca.findById(marcaId)
}
```

but I can't mock Sql Class and see this error:

> groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Ambiguous method overloading for method groovy.sql.Sql#.
>
> Cannot resolve which method to invoke for [null] due to overlapping prototypes between:
>       [interface java.sql.Connection]
>       [interface javax.sql.DataSource]

Comment: What does your test look like? You're getting the exception because dataSource is null and groovy doesn't know which Sql constructor you're trying to call as there are 2 which take a single argument

Comment: I note that, dataSource is null but how I mock this?

Comment: Are all the other tables in your query also Grails domain objects? You may not need to use dataSource like this, take a look at this for various ways of querying the DB http://tatiyants.com/how-and-when-to-use-various-gorm-querying-options/

Answer (score 0):

The code that queries the id should be in a separate service that you can then mock.

Answer (score 0):

From this [Forum](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Can-grails-have-two-different-DB-connections-am-writing-a-reporting-server-td4654542.html):

> Service/datasource definition has to happen outside of the method.
>   Spring will then inject the beans.

Try something like this:

```
FooController { 
        def dataSource_mydb 

        def barAction() { 
                def sql = new Sql(dataSource_mydb) 
        } 
}
```

Comment: Alright, but you can me show how I do test for this controller?